# How to draw SVG shapes at a specific position (dependent on the xAxis)

Tags: javascript, svg, highcharts

I have a chart in Highcharts (to be more specific: it's a Highstocks chart, candlesticks type) and now I want to add some SVG shapes to it.

I know there is this renderer object, but it only accepts x- and y-coordinates relative to the canvas.

What I need is to add some shapes at a specific TIME (xAxis), so I either need it to accept x/y vales as the chart coordinates (not the canvas coordinates) (which I clearly doubt is possible) or we need to get the x/y-canvas-position of a specific point inside the chart.

Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To draw SVG shape and move it with the zoom , there is two ways i used the first one just take it as an idea and see if you can do it better than me , second way always works

*the first way*

Get the x coordinate for this shape : 
    as you know highstock use unix time , so lets say you want to add your shape at X data = 1326844540000 , now get the x position for 1326844540000 according to series[i]  i will assume that you have one series so use series[0] , here is how you get the x-coor :

```
               $.each(chart.series[0].points, function(index,value){
                         if(value.category == 1326847170000 ) 
                         console.log(this.plotX) ;
                 });
```

now use `.append()` to add your SVG :

```
   var myrect = $(".highcharts-series-group") ; 
    $(myrect).append(<your svg goes here with 
            x ="you have it from the previous code " y="")
```

this code will go inside (xAxis - events - setExtremes ) And o nchart load as well

*the recommended way*

the recommended and guranteed way is to create a flag give it an id and then you can do what ever you want by editing the `attr()` of this flag

**UPDATE**

- if you add a flag to your chart flags by default transform when zooming so you don't need to be worry about moving your element every time rangeselector or zoom change .
- if you give your flag id it will be easily selected using jquery
- see this : 
  [image]
- the fourth  path in the highlighted `<g>` tag is what you will edit to draw what ever you want

Comment: Your "first way" is the way I've solved the problem so far but it's still not 'perfect'. There seem to be some deviations from the exact positions, don't know...
And I don't quite understand your "recommended way"... could you please add some explaining words? :)

Answer (score 2):

You can extend existing symbols via

```
$.extend(Highcharts.Renderer.prototype.symbols, {
    newSymbol: function() {
        return [//SVG path as Array];
    }
});
```

[Here is a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hfrntt/zAxPQ/10/) demonstrating that

Comment: This seems to be a nice way but I don't seem to get it right! I'd like to define my own, let's say, circle which I can put at a desired x/y-location, but if I change the x/y-values inside the data section it only adjusts the xAxis while the circle stays exactly where it was.
Example here (with a square in this case): [Example](http://jsfiddle.net/X3EA7/)

Answer (score 1):

You can use graphics to replace a certain data point.  The following [**example**](http://jsfiddle.net/dPqg7/8/) demonstrates this ability.  In the below example a specific point is being replaced by a graphic.  It happens to be the highest point that needs to be graphed.

```
data: [7.0, 6.9, 9.5, 14.5, 18.2, 21.5, 25.2, {
  y: 26.5,
  marker: {symbol: 'url(http://www.highcharts.com/demo/gfx/sun.png)'}
}, 23.3, 18.3, 13.9, 9.6]
```